# Create couples of words in every possible combination from array

Tags: php, arrays, string

My mind is a bit numb at the moment,

suppose i have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => love
)
```

I'd like to create couples of possible combinations (minus one val),

such as

```
foo bar
bar love
foo love
```

and not their opposite (but that's easier)

```
bar foo
love bar
love foo
```

of course the array can be of more elements, and in such cases i'd like to find

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => love
    [3] => test
)

foo bar love
bar love test
love test foo

foo love test
bar test foo
love test bar
```

and so on...

any idea?

thanks!

Comment: So you need to make combinations of every element in the array but one, no matter how many elements are in the array?

Comment: Is "foo bar love" not a possible combination from your first example? And "foo bar love test" a possible combination from your last example? I don't understand how / why /if you're limiting the combinations you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, what I'm trying to achieve here is a combination of words that will be passed to a search engine. the case is this, suppose I have reached a limit where I have finished related items to a 4 words query string. at this point I'm trying to see for all the n-1 strings if there's something to suggest. of course the search engine will select the best n-1 combination, but that's another story.

Comment: @surreal Dreams, yes, exactly

Comment: You do realize that this is incredibly intensive task O(n-1!) for any amount of data more then 20 this is not feasible

Comment: @Ivan Yes, i do, I'm going to limit it to a decent number of words. the search engine is pretty solid though, i think he won't mind (sphinxsearch). Ah! of course this table i'm searching on is just a bunch of previous queries made, so in the sphinx realm it's not a big of a deal, it's just a few millions records with just a few words per record and the rank of each string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll strongly suggest you not to go that route, as the complexity of the algorithm which is required to generate this is O((n)!)  so this is not feasible for any arrays larger then 20 elements.
Event for array of 10 elements there will be 3628800 possible combinations for array with 15 - 1307674368000 for 100 - 9e+157 (that's a 9 and 157 zeros)

Well I didn't want to, but here it is. This will generate all possible combinations(with n-1 lenght) of any array (length n). I would not recommend to run it with the array length more then 7.

```
    $array = array('foo','bar','love','test');
function getAllCombinations($array)
{
    if (count($array)==1)
        return ($array);
    $res = array();
    foreach ($array as $i=>$val)
    {
        $tArray = $array;
        unset($tArray[$i]);
        $subRes = getAllCombinations($tArray);
        foreach ($subRes as $t)
        {
            $res[]= $val.' '.$t;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

foreach ($array as $key=>$val)
{
    $tArray = $array;
    unset($tArray[$key]);
    $res = getAllCombinations($tArray);
    foreach ($res as $t)
        echo $t.'<br />';
}
```

If you will use this with only 4 elements in array and without duplicates,  here is shorter and faster solution:

```
$array = array('foo','bar','love','test');
for ($i1=0; $i1<count($array);$i1++)
{
    for ($i2=$i1+1; $i2<count($array);$i2++)
    {
        for ($i3=$i2+1; $i3<count($array);$i3++)
        {
            echo $array[$i1].' '.$array[$i2].' '.$array[$i3].'<br />';  
        }   
    }   
}
```

if you sort initial array alphanumerically, the result will be ordered alphanumerically as well

Comment: I get this, but I don't need to find (foo, bar and bar, foo) I'll go with bar, foo only (in alphabetical order).

Comment: I've added php example of a function which will do the job. It killed my server after i've entered array with 8 elements :)

Comment: sorry about that! I'm currently investigating a decent way to have it sorted. I'll let you guys know later.

Comment: what i see wrong in this function is that it doesn't lose one word from the array. see above why i need this, in short i need combinations such as foo bar love, love test bar (ie, all possible combinations minus one item)

Comment: Yes, it's beautiful. I will keep it down to max 4 elements, don't want to melt the server. I'll test it a bit and then I'll accept the answer. thanks!

Comment: only problem so far, is to avoid combinations such as foo bar love and bar love foo, because each string will be normalized in the alphabetical order. but i can do that myself :)

Comment: I've update my answer to add a solution for an array of 4 elements, no duplicate results, and orderd results

Comment: this is such a complicated solution. You don't need all the loops. Just take one loop and then don't add the certain element if it has the same index as the current index to be left out. You can see it in my solution below and I really don't know why you think my solution would not work.

Answer (score 4):

```
function getAllCombinations($array){
    $combinations = array();
    foreach ($array as $x) 
        foreach ($array as $y) {
            if($x != $y && !in_array($y.' '.$x,$combinations ))
                array_push($combinations, $x.' '.$y);       
        }
    return $combinations ;
}
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo bar
    [1] => foo love
    [2] => bar love
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you want to get, but I think the following should do the job (if you want to do what I think you want):

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
    $text = "";
    for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($array); $j++) {
        if ($i != $j) {
            $text = $text." ".$array[$j];
        }
    }
    echo $text;
}
```

Comment: Just to nitpick (and I'm sure this can be debated), I've found that the distinction is $i and $j is dangerously vague. When I need an iterator within an iterated loop, I use $i, $c , $q and $k, because those characters are visually distinct. Just my two cents. :)

Comment: I'm doing some tests here, it seems to be working fine. When I'm finished doing tests I'll tell if it's alright. thanks a lot

Comment: This will work only with array which have 3 elements. This script will not handle second example in your question(foo bar love test).

Comment: what is this about? Why would it not handle the second example? It takes into account all tupels where exactly one element is left out. But not those which have length n-2 and so on and the tupels are all only printed once, which is all as desired as I understand the question. I also don't know why the accepted answer was taken away from this, would be happy about a reason why this should not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Math_Combinatorics](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics) package.

Example Code:

```
$combinatorics = new Math_Combinatorics;
$set = array(
'one'   => 'foo',
'two'   => 'bar',
'three' => 'love'
);
$combinations = $combinatorics->combinations($set, 2);
print_r($combinations);
```

2 is the number of words to be combined.

Output at my end:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (   
        [one] => foo
        [two] => bar
    )
  [1] => Array
    (   
        [one] => foo
        [three] => love
    )
  [2] => Array
    (   
        [two] => bar
        [three] => love
    )
)
```